# MSBuild task could not be loaded error

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have this situation, I am using Yahoo Yui Compressor and my MSBuild file contains this line

```
<UsingTask TaskName="CompressorTask" AssemblyFile="..\Lib\Minification\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll" />
```

This path that I have specified is relative to where the build script (in which this line exists) is.

I have these files in the Minification folder

EcmaScript.NET.modified.dll
New BSD License.txt
Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll
Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll

I can't figure out if the following error on building is due to

1. Wrong path being specified
2. Missing dlls or other files
3. Some other reason

The error is

> C:\Builds\Mcfc\UI\Latest\MCFC\scripts\main.xml(270,5): error MSB4062:
>   The "CompressorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   C:\Builds\Mcfc\UI\Latest\MCFC\scripts..\Lib\Minification\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. Done
>   Building Project "C:\Builds\Mcfc\UI\Latest\MCFC\scripts\main.xml"
>   (Deploy target(s)) -- FAILED.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone?  Really stuck on this one.  Am I missing a dll?

Comment: Try the fusion logs (fuslogvw.exe) to see if you are missing a dependency.

Comment: Fusion info: http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2007/11/debugging-with-fusion-logger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the path that is in the error message :-)
You are missing a "\" between scripts and the ..

C:\Builds\Mcfc\UI\Latest\MCFC**scripts..**\Lib\Minification\

Comment: I don't think anything is missing.

Comment: do you actually have a directory called "scripts.."? I assumed you had the ".." to move one directory up. If you do want to move one level up you need to add a "\" between scripts and ".."

Comment: I do have a directory called scripts.  I'll test your theory.